# How to avoid entering strings already present in a list

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, struct

In this piece of code I'm trying to check if a string (in my case the name of a club) is already entered from standard input. My goal is to avoid entering a name already present in the list, but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks all.

```
gets(club[i].name);
if(i != 0){
    for(left = 0; left < i; left++){
        for(right = i; right > 0; right--){
            outcome = strcmp(club[left].name, club[right].name);
            if(outcome == 0){   
                printf("You already entered this team. Pick another one: \n");
                gets(club[i].name);
            }
        }
    }
}
i++;
break;
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. It has no bounds checking and was removed from the language.

Comment: I don't understand why you're using nested loops. You just want to compare this name with all the previous names, you don't need to compare all names with eachother.

Comment: Actually I have to compare every single string entered with the previous names. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: You enter a name, you compare it with all the previous names. But you don't need to compare all the previous names with each other, since you know they're not duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the algo. (Besides, use `fgets` instead of `gets`)

You should compare against `[i]`, not the other values.

This is simpler than the algo left/right:

```
int ok = 1;
for(int j = 0; j < i && ok ; j++){
   ok = strcmp(club[j].name, club[i].name);
}
if ( ! ok) {
   // ask again on the same 'i'
}
```

AFAIU, `i` is the last item, so `j` goes from `0` to `i-1`.

You don't need nested loops, because each input has already been checked against the previous ones. So when a new one comes, you only need to compare it with the previous values.

edit: If `n` is the number of items (item `i` is currently being input, but is not always the latest one), use that algo instead

```
int ok = 1;
for(int j = 0; j < n && ok ; j++){
   ok = j == i || strcmp(club[j].name, club[i].name);
}
if ( ! ok) {
   // ask again on the same 'i'
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `j < n && ok` where `n` is the number of elements of the list instead of `j < i && ok`?

Comment: Based on OP's code, I'm assuming the last item (currently being input) is `[i]`. I don't see any `n`. I added the `n` code anyway :-)

Comment: Yes, it seems, OP choosed a very bad name, `i` usually stands for iterator :(

Answer (score 0):

Just talk about your logic. Except for redundant comparisons, I think you need to **reset the value of left and break inner loop**.

Following your logic, the code should be:

```
gets(club[i].name);
if(i != 0){
    for(left = 0; left < i; left++){
        for(right = i; right > 0; right--){
            outcome = strcmp(club[left].name, club[right].name);
            if(outcome == 0){   
                printf("You already entered this team. Pick another one: \n");
                gets(club[i].name);
                left = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
i++;
break;
```